# spark dataframe write issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

I have this DF:

```
val df1 = df.filter("brand like '%\"%'").select("brand", "edited_brand").show(10, false)
+----------------------+----------------------+  
|brand                 |edited_brand          |  
+----------------------+----------------------+  
|"carter's"            |"carter's"            |  
|"carter's"            |"carter's"            |  
|"the children's place"|"the children's place"|  
|"the children's place"|"the children's place"|  
|"the children's place"|"the children's place"|  
+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I write the dataframe to hdfs using the below statement:

```
df.filter("brand like '%\"%'").select("brand", "edited_brand").write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").save("/user/xyz/brand_output")
```

then I ran the below hadoop command to see the contents of one of the files created

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/xyz/brand_output/part-r-00000-e9b284f4-eaf8-4782-9a1c-88ca0af10714.csv
"\"carter's\""|"\"carter's\""  
"\"the children's place\""|"\"the children's place\""  
"\"the children's place\""|"\"the children's place\""  
...
```

I'm concerned about "carter's"(the column content has "(double quotes) in it) being converted to "\"carter's\"". For other records those doesn't contain " in it are being written in normal fashion. For ex - old navy|old navy

I would like to know why the data is getting written in such fashion and how to get rid of those escape characters.

Comment: |(pipe) is the delimiter i passed while writing the dataframe to hdfs. That's not the problem. I'm concerned about "carter's"(the column content has "(double quotes) in it) being converted to "\"carter's\"". For other records those doesn't contain " in it are being written in normal fashion. For ex - old navy|old navy

Comment: Resolved this by using - option("quote", "\u0000") while writing the dataframe. opData8.filter("brand like '%\"%'").select("brand", "edited_brand").write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").option("quote", "\u0000").save("/user/xyz/brand_output")

Answer (score 0):

Initial string value contains quotes: |"carter's" |
When this string written to CSV, initial string have to be stored as it is, with quotes, and also in CSV format strings embraced with quotes - means, additional quotes will be added.

Quotes from original string are escaped with \", and all string included in additional quotes according to CSV format, all correct.

For avoid escaping, quotes can be removed in original string, for example with "DataFrameNaFunctions.replace".
Also quotes in CSV can be ommited with "quoteMode", details here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by using - option("quote", "\u0000") while writing the dataframe.

```
df.filter("brand like '%\"%'").select("brand", "edited_brand").write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").option("quote", "\u0000").save("/user/xyz/brand_output")
```